# Typescript: Is it possible to have a Generic type that is an extension of another type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

We have some code where we define many types that are generic, but extend another type. Our code looks like this (I removed the properties for clarity):

```
type SortDescriptor<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
};

interface Config<T extends Record<string, unknown>> {
}

interface TableDataSort<T extends Record<string, unknown>> {
}
```

as you can see, `<T extends Record<string, unknown>>` is used three times, and I would like to extract that to another type, say `ExtendedRecord`:

```
type SortDescriptor<ExtendedRecord> = {
};

interface Config<ExtendedRecord> {
}

interface TableDataSort<ExtendedRecord> {
}
```

I have tried defining `type ExtendedRecord<T> = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>;`which does not compile, and `type ExtendedRecord<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = T;` which does compile but it does not seem to do what I want.

Comment: Is the `T extends` part important? Or do you want a common type only?

Comment: No, there is no shorthand for generic constraints; you can't abstract away the `extends` in `type Foo<T extends Bar> = {}`.  I can't find a specific source that says this explicitly (there isn't a list of all features that *don't* exist in TypeScript) so I'm not sure how to answer this other than just "no, sorry".  Is that what you want to see, or am I missing something?  (If you reply, please write @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz your answer is good enough, I was wondering if it is even possible and "no, sorry" is a valid response. ```type Response = 'yes, like this...' | 'no, sorry';```

Comment: @Edwin yes, the extends part is what I want to abstract away so I don't have to repeat it everywhere