# Save in a type a repeated generic T in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In my application i have many interfaces where i am using: `T extends Values`. T is a generic and `Values` represents a interface.

```
interface A<T extends Values> {
  name: User<T>;
  errors: Errors;
}
interface B<T extends Values> {
  name: User2<T>;
  data: Data;
}
...
```

Question: Is it possible to save `T extends Values` into a separate `type` like `type GTest = T extends Values` and after that to be able to use this type for all interfaces where i am using this construction?

Comment: Nope, it isn't.

Comment: Same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73729239/2887218) so if someone is up to writing a "sorry, no" answer to one of these, then the other one should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Asking do you want to a) awoid writing `extends Values` in every `interface Int<T extends Values>`(then no same as you can't remove type from function args) b) avoid writing `Int<MyValues>` in every place you use the interface (then you can) or something else?